# Troubleshooting CPU Utilization Spikes on AWS ECS

Tags: web-hosting, performance, amazon-aws, cpu, load

Our production system has frequent spikes in CPU Utilization. These spikes occur even when the application does not have high usage. Here is an example of how we have CPU Utilization spikes frequently.
[image: Snapshot from Last 24 hours]

The CPU Utilization also spikes to 100% very often
[image: 100% Utilization]

I'm new to ECS and I wanted some advise on how to troubleshoot this. Here are some details that might be helpful:

- There are no background jobs running
- No deployments occurred during those spikes

Questions that I have:

- Is this expected behavior that the average Utilization is significantly different than the maximum?
- What is the best approach to identify the source of the CPU spike?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ssh into this ec2 instance and run `top` on it?